# All answer comments disappeared

Tags: support, deleted-comments

There were several comments for [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49431919/3731501) yesterday from several persons. All of them were regular comments that shouldn't be normally flagged for deletion. My own comment explained the answer's weak side (the answer directly addresses the question which is XY problem). The answer has been edited since that moment but not to the point where the comments would be considered irrelevant.

Today there are no comments in this answer.

Where have they gone? How is it possible that several appropriate comments (all of them) have been wiped at once?

Comment: Where have they gone: someone flagged and a moderator agreed with the flag. Were there no argument going on those comments at all? It was all nice and civil?

Comment: @yivi No arguing at all. They were all civil and on-topic.

Comment: How *many* comments were there?  A *lot*?  Might've been a good reason to get rid of 'em.

Comment: @Makoto Around 5. IIRC, the poster and the OP discussed the answer. I cannot imagine what would be the reason to flag all of them and accept that flag. It is strange to see them disappearing so I suspected that there was database glitch.

Comment: @estus:  Comments can and have been known to be deleted at *whim*, since they're temporal anyway.  I strongly doubt it's a database glitch, but it'd be interesting to know why they did get removed if there was only five.

Answer (score 20):

Comments serve a specific purpose in Stack Exchange. Generally speaking, they  should either ask for clarification or offer suggestions about how to improve the post. Random asides and other chatter are generally considered noise and are often flagged and removed.

Here are the comments in question:

> <solution with code>
>      :
>      :
>
> Comments:
>
> - The fact that this is even possible in javascript is so disgusting.
> - Seems to be a pretty poor interview question, to be honest. Not sure I would want a developer to implement such a method.
> - Javascript has many parts. Some are good, and some are bad. The problem is interview questions that exploit these quirks
> - It's unfortunate we can't get num this way, so the class doesn't make sense
> - This is working, but deceze's answer seems right too
> - whatever works for you

None of these comments are asking for clarification nor making suggestions to improve the post. They express a distaste for the original interview question and take some shots at JavaScript.

It's not like such comments are single-handedly destroying this thread, but in terms of keeping the Q&A tight and noise free, if somebody took the time to flag them, I probably would have hit `delete` instead of `dismiss` too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I believe the important role of the comments on SO is that they provide additional relevant information, most heavily upvoted comments belong to this kind. [Comments are often used to ask for clarification on, suggest corrections to, and *provide meta-information about posts*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work). My comment specified the problem in the answer (*It's unfortunate we can't get num this way*). And I ended up posting my own answer instead.

Comment: Is there anything discussing whether or not clarification comments that aren't necessarily incorporated into a post remain on a post?